# How to enable WSS with Java Websocket API

Tags: java, ssl, websocket

I've developed a Java 8 webapp that runs on Tomcat 8. This webapp uses a WebSocket to communicate with a JavaScript client via ws://. I'm using the Java Server Websocket API to create the websocket like this:

```
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnError;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;

@ServerEndpoint("/asyncImage")
public class AsynchronousImageWebSocket {
    
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onOpen::" + session.getId());        
    }
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session) {
        System.out.println("onClose::" +  session.getId());
    }
    
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, Session session) throws Exception {
        ...
    }

}
```

Now that the Webapp approaches production, it must be accessed via SSL and, according to the mixed content policy, the websocket has to use secure communication via wss:// too. Tomcat runs behind an Apache server which handles all outside communication via HTTPS and forwards the requests to Tomcat in plain HTTP, so Tomcat itself does not use secure communication yet.

I was surprised by the lack of documentation on that topic. I couldn't find information on how to do it, neither could I find a statement saying that wss is not supported.

Could somebody give me a short comment on how (and if) the Java Server Websocket API supports secure communication? Is it maybe enought to switch Tomcat to HTTPS? I hope I don't have to change technology on the last meters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you activate SSL in Tomcat for your application? What was the result trying to access your websocket via wss://? I did the same once for Jetty and it worked out of the box. The only change I had to make was to generate the websocket URL in the HTML/JS page with wss:// for a https:// page.

Comment: No, I didn't activate SSL in Tomcat yet (see my edited question). This could be complicated, especially on the administrative side, so I was hoping for a confirmation that this is actually working. I'm afraid I have to build a test environment somewhere to confirm this then. I let you know of my findings once I'm done.

Comment: Sure, you have to build a test environment. How will you check the functionality whithout a proper test environment?